# Algebraic differential cryptanalysis

Tags: cryptanalysis

I have been studying on algebraic methods on cryptanalysis of block ciphers.
[This is where I am reading from currently](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://eprint.iacr.org/2008/177.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjOtZGp_NvyAhVD_XMBHTKjDCIQFnoECAQQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3kcu6P8uwtkWDurxhbP01O)

I need some help to understand Attack C.

Excluding equations from the first r rounds till which the differential characteristic holds, we are just left with the SBox equations and one constraint from the input difference to the $(r+1)^{th}$ round S Boxes as a consequence of the r round differential, for each of the plaintext pairs.

I cannot understand how they are considering an equivalent structure with 2R -1 rounds from C' to C''.

A brief explanation would be really helpful.